# Finding a code to delete '!' from cells in a certain range using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I am using pandas to read excel files and "clean it up"

The Problem:
Assuming cell range is from [0, 0] to [8, 8]
I would like to delete the '!' character from cells within the range outlined.
For example, some cells value hold '0.02!' or 'incl!ne'.

I have tried some code in the past which targets the data_frame in general but not so specific to the range outlined - I am a novice when it comes to python!

I would like the output to be '0.02' or 'inclne'

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.iloc` and `replace`. Given `df`:

```
0        1        2  ...          8        9  
0    0.02!    0.02!  incl!ne  ...    incl!ne  incl!ne  
1    0.02!    0.02!  incl!ne  ...    incl!ne  incl!ne  
2  incl!ne    0.02!  incl!ne  ...      0.02!  incl!ne  
3  incl!ne    0.02!  incl!ne  ...      0.02!    0.02!  
4  incl!ne  incl!ne  incl!ne  ...      0.02!  incl!ne  
5    0.02!    0.02!    0.02!  ...      0.02!  incl!ne  
6    0.02!    0.02!  incl!ne  ...    incl!ne  incl!ne  
7    0.02!  incl!ne    0.02!  ...    incl!ne  incl!ne  
8  incl!ne    0.02!  incl!ne  ...    incl!ne  incl!ne  
9  incl!ne  incl!ne    0.02!  ...      0.02!  incl!ne  

df.iloc[0:8, 0:8] = df.iloc[0:8, 0:8].replace('!', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7  \
0     0.02     0.02   inclne     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02   
1     0.02     0.02   inclne   inclne   inclne   inclne   inclne   inclne   
2   inclne     0.02   inclne   inclne   inclne     0.02   inclne   inclne   
3   inclne     0.02   inclne   inclne     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02   
4   inclne   inclne   inclne   inclne   inclne   inclne   inclne     0.02   
5     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02   inclne     0.02     0.02     0.02   
6     0.02     0.02   inclne     0.02   inclne     0.02     0.02     0.02   
7     0.02   inclne     0.02     0.02   inclne     0.02     0.02     0.02   
8  incl!ne    0.02!  incl!ne    0.02!  incl!ne  incl!ne  incl!ne  incl!ne   
9  incl!ne  incl!ne    0.02!  incl!ne  incl!ne  incl!ne  incl!ne  incl!ne   

         8        9  
0  incl!ne  incl!ne  
1  incl!ne  incl!ne  
2    0.02!  incl!ne  
3    0.02!    0.02!  
4    0.02!  incl!ne  
5    0.02!  incl!ne  
6  incl!ne  incl!ne  
7  incl!ne  incl!ne  
8  incl!ne  incl!ne  
9    0.02!  incl!ne
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```py
df.replace(“!”, “”, regex=True)
```

Or you can [do the same](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) on columns (Series) as well.

Comment: Have you tested? You need `regex=True`; otherwise `replace` will only replace _string exactly matching to_replace will be replaced with value_.